# Delete words in sentence but not between double quotes

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I wish to format a sentence with replacements but not between the double quotes.

**Example**, this sentence:

```
$remplacement = ['the', 'in']; // words who must be deleted
$sentence = "the sea" OR the sea AND "the sea" in the world.
```

**Should be**:

> "the sea" OR sea AND "the sea" the world.

I think we can do use preg_replace or preg_match.
I found the regex who take the text around the doubles quotes:

```
'/[^"]+(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*"[^"]*)*$)/'
```

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: not replaced but deleted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore the quoted words with PCRE verbs. You then can implode the terms with an "or" and just replace them. You should use word boundaries so partial matches aren't replaced.

```
$remplacement = ['the', 'in'];
$sentence = '"the sea" OR the sea AND "the sea" in the world.';
echo preg_replace('/([\'"]).*?\1(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\b(' . implode ('|', $remplacement) . ')\b/', '', $sentence);
```

https://3v4l.org/ZELoV

Your example is incorrect though, right? At the end `the world` should also become `world`.

If you care about the double spacing you could use:

```
preg_replace('/\h\h+/', ' ',
```

to get rid of that.

https://3v4l.org/pqCH3

Comment: Its seems ok, but we must search the words and not the part of words, so we must add a space arround the search in the rege, right ?

Because for now, if you add in the $remplacement 'd', the d of the word 'world' will be deleted

Comment: You'll need to provide an example with the `d` I can't reproduce that https://3v4l.org/1a7lC. The `fané` vs. `fanée` issue can be resolved by adding the `u` modifier. https://3v4l.org/GikTB The word boundaries should make it so partial matches aren't matched.

Comment: Ok I was speaking of 't' of word 'renaît' and not the 'd' of world. sorry.
The last problem is I am in php 7.2